# (Java Sockets) Mime multipart alternative in java to download attachments with POP3

Tags: java, sockets, email, attachment, pop3

I'm trying to download email attachment using POP3. I connect to Gmail using Java Sockets and using pop3 commands I retrieve my emails.

My quoestion is java has other alteenatives to download attachments **without using mime multipart and javax mail package**?

Comment: POP3 merely gives you the **raw** email data.  You would have to parse it yourself, or use a third-party parser, if not a parser built in to Java itself.  The only other alternative is to switch to IMAP instead, which provides much more detailed access to portions of a given email, like individual attachments.

Comment: I had assigment to do program to read emails with pop3 protocol. Which I already reported. Only part I could not figure it out was attachments. But I guessing I will have to finish it with javax mail. :)